# Wordpress plugin. Get query from yahoo

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin but there is a problem getting the query.

Here is the code:

```
function getQuery($stockName){

$yql= 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("';

$yql = $yql.implode('","', $stockName);

var_dump ($stockName);

$yql = $yql.'")';

var_dump ($yql);

return $yql;
}
```

`var_dump ($stockName)` returns the option that I configure in the admin_menu; in this case, GOOG.

But the implode doesn't work because it returns the array `$stockName` instead of the expected string.

What I get:

```
$yql = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("Array")'
```

but what I expect:

```
$yql = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("GOOG")'
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you show the array itself ??

Comment: How do you prepare the `$stockName` variable before you pass it to the function ?